# Understanding Firebase's rules for user-write, global-read

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am building a simple Firebase application with AngularJS.  This app authenticates users through Google. Each user has a list of books.  Anyone can see books, even if they are not authenticated. Only the creator of a book can edit it.  However, individual users need to be able to record that they've read a book even if someone else added it.

I have `rules.json` like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "book": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
      }
      ".read": true,
    }
  }
}
```

And I am trying to write a book simply with:

```
$firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL + "/book")).$add({foo: "bar"})
```

I get a "permission denied" error when trying to do this although I do seem to be able to `read` books I create manually in Forge.

I also think that the best way to store readers would be to make it a property of the book (a set of `$uid` for logged-in readers).  `".write"` seems like it would block this, so how would I do that?

```
"$uid": {
  ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
  "readers": {
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
},
```

It seems like a validation rule would be appropriate here as well ... something like `newData.val() == auth.uid`, but I'm not sure how to validate that `readers` is supposed to be an array (or specifically a set) of these values.

Comment: As far as I see your `.read` rule is correct, since your `ref` is to the `/book` node. But I don't get how you want the `.write` to function. Note that `$add` generates a so-called push-id, which is not the same as `$uid`. It looks more likely that you have `/book/$bookid` and under that e.g. `creator` that has the `uid` of the creator. You can then do set `book/$bookid/.write` to `auth != null && (!data.exists() || auth.uid == data.child('creator').val())`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is `"$bookid"` different from `"$uid"`?  Should I just create a rule like `"book/$bookid"` or nested `"book"` and `"$bookid"`/`"$uid"` rules (or does it not matter)

Comment: Anything starting with a `$` is just a variable, it can have any name. But `$uid` is typically used for "user id" nodes, so nodes that are identified by `auth.uid`. Since you're adding books by `$add`, they are identified by a push-id.

Comment: Great question btw. Sorry for trying to address is in comments. Full answer below now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's start with a sample JSON snippet:

```
  "book": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": { //this is the generated unique id
      "title": "Structuring Data",
      "url": "https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html",
      "creator": "twiter:4916627"

    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "title": "Securing Your Data",
      "url": "https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html",
      "creator": "twiter:209103"
    }
  }
```

So this is a list with two links to articles. Each link was added by a different user, who is identified by `creator`. The value of `creator` is a `uid`, which is a value that Firebase Authentication provides and that is available in your security rules under `auth.uid`.

I'll split your rule into two parts here:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "book": {
      ".read": true,
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I see your `.read` rule is correct, since your ref is to the /book node.

```
$firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL + "/book"))
```

Note that the ref below would not work, since you don't have read-access to the top-level node.

```
$firebaseArray(new Firebase(URL))
```

Now for the `.write` rules. First off is that you'll need to grant users write-access on the `book` level already. Calling `$add` means that you're adding a node under that level, so write-access is required.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "book": {
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

*I leave the `.read` rules out here for clarity.*

This allows any authenticated user to write to the book node. This means that they can add new books (which you want) and change existing books (which you don't want).

Your last requirement is most tricky. Any user can add a book. But once someone added a book, only that person can modify it. In Firebase's Security Rules, you'd model that like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "book": {
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$bookid": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid == data.child('creator').val()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this last rule, we allow writing of a specific book if *either* there is no current data in this location (i.e. it's a new book) or if the data was created by the current user.

In the above example `$bookid` is just a variable name. The important thing is that the rule under it is applied to every book. If needed we could use `$bookid` in our rules and it would hold `-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY` or `-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE` respectively. But in this case, that is not needed.

Comment: I haven't actually managed to test it out yet, but under `$bookid` I have `readers: {".write": "auth !== null"}` -- this should allow any user to write to the `readers` property, right?

Comment: It looks OK, but it's hard to be certain without seeing it completely. Nesting data with different security constraints often leads to headaches. I'd put the readers into a separate top-level `book_readers` node, so `/book_readers/$bookid/$readerid`. That way you can isolate the security rules for the readers. See the documentation section about "avoiding nested data" here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data

Answer (score 2):

First off the "permission denied" error. You are getting this error because you are trying to write directly in the "book" node instead of "book/$uid".

Example of what you do now:

```
  "book": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": { //this is the generated unique id
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "-JRHTHaKuITFIhnj02kE": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
```

In your rules you have a global rule for write set to false so that will be the default and next to that you have made a rule for the specific node book/$uid. So when trying to write directly in "book" it will take the default rule that was set to false. Have a look at [Securing your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html) for more information about firebase rules.

And for the last part of your question i suggest you take a look at [Structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) for more information about the best ways to structure your data inside firebase.

So taka a good look at what and how you want to save and write in firebase and make sure your rules are structured accordingly.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, `.$add` won't write directly to the `book` node but will write to a sub node with a `$uid`.  I think I just need to change the write rule.  I don't think there is a problem with my suggested structure since it's just recording if a user has read a book -- I just want to make sure that what is written is a valid, unique user.

Comment: What is happening is that .$add creates a unique id like using the push() function does. $uid is the user id.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I just added an example to my answer.